# Program Crashes While Setting Data in Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a project and every time I go to set example[4].m_dArray[3], the program crashes.  I can set the value of every other variable up until I get to example[4].m_dArray[3]. Any help would be appreciated!

Prog1Class.h:

```
#include "Prog1Struct.h"
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


class Prog1Class
{
private:
    Prog1Struct example[4];
public:
    Prog1Class();
    ~Prog1Class ();
    void setStructData();
    void getStructData();
    void ptrFunction();
    void refFunction();
    void printStruct();
    void printData();
};
```

Prog1Struct.h:

```
  #pragma once
#include <string.h>
struct Prog1Struct {
  int m_iVal;
  double m_dArray[4];
  char m_sLine[80];
};
```

Prog1Class.cpp:

```
#include "Prog1Class.h"
#include "Prog1Struct.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

Prog1Class::Prog1Class()
{
}
Prog1Class::~Prog1Class()
{
    delete &example[4];
}
int main()
{
    Prog1Class *aClass = new Prog1Class();
    aClass->setStructData();
    aClass->printData();
    return 0;
}
void Prog1Class::setStructData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> example[i].m_iVal;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
    cout << endl << "Enter a double: ";
    cin >> example[i].m_dArray[j];
    }
    cout << endl << "Enter a string: ";
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    cin.getline(example[i].m_sLine, 80, '\n');
    cout << endl;
    }
}
void Prog1Class::getStructData()
{

}

void Prog1Class::printData()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    cout << example[i].m_iVal;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
    cout << example[i].m_dArray[j];
    }
    cout << example[i].m_sLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the header files. There's not enough information to disgnose the problem let alone offer a solution. But `delete &example[4];` is completely wrong.

Comment: Two things: use `<string>` header instead of `<string.h>` and in `main ` don't create an object on the heap (`Prog1Class *aClass = new Prog1Class();`), just declare a local object (`Prog1Class aClass;`).

Comment: Show us the code where you initialize the `example` array.

Comment: Please show us the code of `Prog1Class.h`.

Comment: stop including string.h in every file; only include things where you use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this

```
class Prog1Class
{
private:
    Prog1Struct example[4];
```

to this

```
class Prog1Class
{
private:
    Prog1Struct example[5];
```

In C++ arrays start at index 0, so an array of size 4 has valid indexes 0 upto 3. You're using `example[4]` so you need an array of (at least) size 5.

You also need to remove `delete &example[4];` from your destructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

First , `delete &example[4];` should be `delete [] example;`

Second, where did you allocate memory for `example`?

Comment: I think nowhere is the likely answer, which would make `delete [] example;` wrong too.

Comment: Yes, I think we need to wait for the header

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the way the `example` object is declared? I'd suspect some mis-allocated or mis-declared problem with it. Your `setStructureData` doesn't do anything ostensibly wrong (assuming the array sizes match and the size of the string is fitting - *it is a char array, not a pointer, correct?*).

Comment: Whoops - rushed with a response. I meant the declaration of the example object.

Answer (score 0):

Array deletion is `delete [] example`, not your way. Also, to use `delete` data needs to be allocated with `new`

Here is small example how to use `new` and `delete`

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
  foo() {std::cout <<"constructed\n";}
  ~foo() {std::cout <<"destroyed\n";}
};

int main () 
{
  foo * pt;

  pt = new foo[3];
  delete[] pt;

  return 0;
}
```

Also the output:

```
constructed
constructed
constructed
destroyed
destroyed
destroyed
```

I gave a lesson about `new/delete` and just now seen real problem:

`example[4]` is out of bounds. If you declare array with 4 elements it means you have indexes `0, 1, 2, 3` and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
> //              ^^^^^
> ```

Your `for` loops should have an ending condition with `i < 4` since your arrays have only 4 spaces. Moreover, your `delete` should be `delete[] example;`.